# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized: While uploading file in document library using App Based Token Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, document-library, file-upload, token

I am trying to upload a document to the document library using App Based Token authentication in SharePoint Online.

I have referred following [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs) to set up the App Based token and the token successfull worked when I try to read any thing from the site.

But when I try to upload a file using following code,

```
string file = @"Path Of the file";
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(file, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
using (var ctx = new AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, "CLIENTID","CLIENTSECRET"))
{
    try
    {
        ctx.Load(ctx.Web, p => p.Title);
                     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                        Console.WriteLine(ctx.Web.Title);
                     Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, "RelativePathToDocumentLibrary" + "/test.docx", fs, false);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
}
```

It gives me error of

> {"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}

Any suggestion or reference link is most welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the SaveBinaryDirect method does not support app-based authentication. You should use either SharePointOnlineCredentials for your ClientContext or upload files with FileCreationInformation:

```
FileCreationInformation fci = new FileCreationInformation();
fci.Content = data;
fci.Url = url;

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fci);
context.Load(file);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. It worked. Do we have any reference document link from where I can know what operations I cannot do using app-based token?

Comment: Not so many, I do know about two of such methods: File.SaveBinaryDirect and File.OpenBinaryDirect. But have never seen any official documents pointing to those limitations.

Comment: Here is the reference that I was looking for https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly#what-are-the-limitations-when-using-app-only

Comment: `Content` won't work here if the document is over 2MB in file size; you'll need to use `ContentStream` instead. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint